# Vue 3 Storybook

Tags: vue.js, storybook

I have successfully installed Storybook for Vue, but it doesn't seem to handle Vue 3 components very well.

I believe this is because the Vue version is @vue/cli 4.5.11 when I run "vue -V" & the Storybook is 6.1.17 when I run "start-storybook -V"

I don't get how this works. Am I on Vue 3? How do I get Storybook to understand my Vue 3 components?

Here is my package.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "component-library",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Component Library",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@storybook/theming": "^6.1.18",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.1.11",
    "@storybook/addons": "^6.1.18",
    "@storybook/vue": "^6.1.11",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not on Vue 3! Your current version is 2.6.11. You should upgrade your Vue version. Storybook will work with Vue 3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how to do it? I have been looking for hours.. I use npm, not yarn

Comment: You can check out the [official migration guide](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/introduction.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, you are on Vue version `2.6.11`, which isn't Vue 3.

You can easily upgrade your project with the Vue CLI command:

`vue add vue-next`

After that make sure to upgrade Storybook:

`npx sb@next init`

You can checkout the [blog post](https://storybook.js.org/blog/storybook-vue3/) by Storybook about the Vue 3 integration.